# mvc 4 - how to return empty list from webgrid instead of throwing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and C#. I wrote code to display data from a webgrid by retrieving data from database. It worked. But if there is any bad case like database broken or something, it would fail to retrieve data so I would like the webgrid to return empty list or display "No Employee Data"  instead of throwing error. I added if statement in webgrid which seems not working. It still throws error:

> "A data source must be bound bfore this operation can be performed."

Hope you can help solve my code like following:

**EmployeeController:**

```
    var employees = (IEnumerable<Employees>)Session["Employees"] ?? EmployeeService.LoadEmployees(Guid.Empty, string.Empty, null, null, string.Empty, "Error");
```

**index.chstml**

```
   @grid.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(columnName: "ConvertedId", header: "Employee ID", format: (item) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ConvertedId)?string.Empty:item.ConvertedId),
        grid.Column(columnName: "Employee Code", header: "Vendor Name", format: (item) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.EmployeeCode)?string.Empty:item.EmployeeCode),
        grid.Column(columnName: "Date", header: "Date", format: (item) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Date.ToString())?string.Empty:item.Date.ToString()),
        grid.Column(columnName: "Status", header: "Status", format: (item) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Status)?string.Empty:item.Status),

        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a condition statement in you `Index` view by checking the `Model` value, also create a table for when no employees data have been found case, See below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Employees>

<div>
     @if (Model.Any())
     {
        grid.GetHtml(
               //  Your existing code here
           );
     }
     else
     {
         <div class="grid">
             <table>
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>Employee ID</th>
                         <th>Vendor Name</th>
                         <th>Date</th>
                         <th>Status</th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                     <tr>
                         <td colspan="4" align="center">
                             No Employee Datafound
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>         
         </div>
     }
</div>
```